# Convert xml to json without conversion String/Integer?

Tags: java, json, xml, string, format-conversion

I would like to convert **XML** to **JSON**.

Currently, I make this with the lib *org.json* :

```
JSONObject jso = XML.toJSONObject(xmlStr);
```

However, if the XML contains number fields, I would like to have only String fields in the `JSONObject`.

For example:

The XML file is :

```
<ID>3</ID>
<NAME>ApplicationName</NAME>
```

The org.json permits me to have:

```
{
    "ID" : 3,
    "Name" : "ApplicationName"
}
```

The final result has to be :

```
{
    "ID" : "3",
    "Name" : "ApplicationName"
}
```

Comment: That's a tough one. You might have more success deserializing the XML to a Map<String, String> to get everything to be String and then serializing that to JSON. Can't say for certain

Comment: Thanks. But it's possible to deserialize the XML file when it is more complexe than the exemple ?

Comment: I don't see why not. As long as it's a JSON Object and not a JSON Array, using the Map<String, String> should be fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolve mt problem by using the latest version of org.json.

There is a methode to do this :

```
JSONObject jso = XML.toJSONObject(xmlStr, true);
```

The boolean is using to keep the string fields.

Comment: which version is this one accept the boolean flag ? can you plese mentioned here ? we couldnt find in the latest version